# Querying a remote Indexing Service database

Tags: c#, oledb, indexing-service

I'm trying to search the Indexing Service of a remote Windows 2003 server from ASP.NET. There's sample code for this on the MS site, but only for local searches. Here's what I've got so far; the remote server in this example is called "indexserver", isn't on a domain, and has a index called "system":

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSIDXS;User ID=administrator;Password=Password";

        OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText= "SELECT * FROM indexserver.system..FILEINFO";

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Running this gives me the error "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check the OLE DB status if available. No work was done".

Does anyone know how to get this working? All I need to do is query the Index for a filename and get the path of that file back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I discovered that Windows Indexing Service is somewhat depreciated,and Windows Search seems to be the way to go...

Comment: any source code sample using ***Windows Search*** ?